# Error in sculpting, maybe corrupt file

Tags: sculpting, error

Recently I was attempting to sculpt from a tutorial on youtube and I encountered and error where the brush stopped working consistently and I got a line following the cursor instead.  I'm curious if there is anything I can do rather than starting a new file.  The problem does not seem to be attached to the object and it only occurs with the SculptDraw brush.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na, it's fine... you just accidentally got your smooth stroke enabled. Disable it and you will be fine.

[image]